# Lexicographical comparison of tuples of nats

Tags: coq

I'm working with tuples of `nat`s (specifically triples, `nat*nat*nat`) and would like a way to lexicographically compare tuples. Something equivalent to this:

```
Inductive lt3 : nat*nat*nat -> nat*nat*nat -> Prop :=
| lt3_1 : forall n1 n2 n3 m1 m2 m3, n1 < m1 -> lt3 (n1,n2,n3) (m1,m2,m3)
| lt3_2 : forall n1 n2 n3    m2 m3, n2 < m2 -> lt3 (n1,n2,n3) (n1,m2,m3)
| lt3_3 : forall n1 n2 n3       m3, n3 < m3 -> lt3 (n1,n2,n3) (n1,n2,m3).
```

I would like to have proofs of basic properties such as transitivity and well-foundedness. Are there things in the standard library that do most of the work? If not, I'm most interested in well-foundedness. How would I go about proving it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard library has its own [definition](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/stdlib/Coq.Relations.Relation_Operators.html#lexprod) of lexicographic product, along with a [proof](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/stdlib/Coq.Wellfounded.Lexicographic_Product.html) of well-foundedness.  The problem with that definition, however, is that it is stated for dependent pairs:

```
lexprod : forall (A : Type) (B : A -> Type), relation {x : A & B x}
```

If you want, you can instantiate `B` with a constant type family of the form `fun _ => B'`, because the types `A * B'` and `{x : A & B'}` are isomorphic.  But if you want to work directly with the Coq type of regular pairs, you can simply replicate the proofs for a more restricted version of the lexicographic product.  The proof is not very complicated, but it requires a nested induction on the accessibility predicate that defines well-foundedness.

```
Require Import
  Coq.Relations.Relation_Definitions
  Coq.Relations.Relation_Operators.

Set Implicit Arguments.
Unset Strict Implicit.
Unset Printing Implicit Defensive.

Section Lexicographic.

Variables (A B : Type) (leA : relation A) (leB : relation B).

Inductive lexprod : A * B -> A * B -> Prop :=
| left_lex  : forall x x' y y', leA x x' -> lexprod (x, y) (x', y')
| right_lex : forall x y y',    leB y y' -> lexprod (x, y) (x, y').

Theorem wf_trans :
  transitive _ leA ->
  transitive _ leB ->
  transitive _ lexprod.
Proof.
intros tA tB [x1 y1] [x2 y2] [x3 y3] H.
inversion H; subst; clear H.
- intros H.
  inversion H; subst; clear H; apply left_lex; now eauto.
- intros H.
  inversion H; subst; clear H.
  + now apply left_lex.
  + now apply right_lex; eauto.
Qed.

Theorem wf_lexprod :
  well_founded leA ->
  well_founded leB ->
  well_founded lexprod.
Proof.
intros wfA wfB [x].
induction (wfA x) as [x _ IHx]; clear wfA.
intros y.
induction (wfB y) as [y _ IHy]; clear wfB.
constructor.
intros [x' y'] H.
now inversion H; subst; clear H; eauto.
Qed.

End Lexicographic.
```

You can then instantiate this general version to recover, for instance, your definition of the lexicographic product for triples of natural numbers:

```
Require Import Coq.Arith.Wf_nat.

Definition myrel : relation (nat * nat * nat) :=
  lexprod (lexprod lt lt) lt.

Lemma wf_myrel : well_founded myrel.
Proof. repeat apply wf_lexprod; apply lt_wf. Qed.
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not very familiar with dependent pairs. What is `sigT` and `existT`? How would I transfer the result to regular pairs?

Comment: @Arcinde I just added a version that does not require dependent pairs.

Comment: @ArthurAzevedoDeAmorim The proof of Theorem `wf_lexprod` you provide doesn't compile (in Coq version 8.8.2). I fixed it by replacing the `[x]` in the first line by `[x y]` and adding a `generalize dependent y.` before the first induction.