# Is it possible to jointly recurse on a pair of variables in Coq?

Tags: coq, induction

Let's say that I'm trying to prove the following:

```
Theorem le_s_n : forall n m, S n <= S m -> n <= m.
```

I feel like it might be productive to perform induction on the pair `(n, m)`. The cases would be something like `(0, 0)`, `(0, S m')`, `(S n', 0`), and `(S n', S m')`. Is this at all possible?

Comment: You could try to do that but it won't be very productive. A more promising approach is to examine the (inductive) evidence `S n <= S m`.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42520130/lexicographical-comparison-of-tuples-of-nats) to have a glimpse on lexicographic ordering, but I suggest to read @ejgallego comments, that I totally agree with.